# What would happen if Rogue touched Rogue?

Tags: marvel, x-men, rogue

Has Rogue ever encountered someone with the same mutant ability as herself? I.E., they absorb the mental knowledge and physical abilities of someone when they make skin-to-skin contact.

If it hasn't happened, is the encounter between Hope and Rogue the closest its ever come or is there an example involving someone whose powers more closely match Rogue's?

Comment: I googled "Rogue touching herself" and was shocked by what I found.

Comment: I suspect that we can only really answer this either via a Word of God from one of the creators, or from it happening in one of those multiversal crossovers.

Comment: Feedback loop of life exchange creating an explosion, which will be conveniently used in a moment of desperation against the next villain of the week (who's probably the evil 3rd clone? Sure, why not).

Comment: Hairy palms and/or blindness, according to everyone's mom.

Comment: I think if Rogue One touched Rogue Two they would both likely crash. I dunno, maybe Wedge would pull it up and recover but be forced to leave the battle like in Episode IV.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - Or possibly nothing whatsoever would happen. In the media I've seen, it always seems like something was being sucked out of the victim, whether Rogue wants it to or not (which is why she has to wear gloves). In the RW that usually means some kind of potential energy difference between the two objects. So it could be just like two charged objects with the same charge touching each other: They are both already at the "neutral" charge between them, so nothing is forcing the electrons in either to move.

Comment: It's not quite the same, but at one point Rogue touched Leech (cancels out powers), and what happened was described as something like a short circuit.  Leech went unconscious and Rogue lost all her powers for about the normal absorption-duration, but didn't project an anti-power field, and didn't absorb his memories.  Though that was a bit silly because Leech's powers were an automatic field effect and should have cancelled her abilities before she made physical contact.

Comment: @T.E.D. Not sure if you didn't understand my comment or you're teasing me about it... If the former, make sure you read the second sentence of it.

Comment: Rogue takes a person's "Essence" which is more or less their soul without being their soul. She can hold onto it for as long as she likes & as much of it as she likes.She has touched people who are extremely powerful and the result is basically that she doesn't knock them out/get all of their power/etc. If she were to touch herself she'd be essentially taking her own Essence at the same time and the result would be something like a body exchange probably. In MvC games she has and the initiator gets strength i think. Also the universe thing in Marvel happening now makes it likely to happen soon

Comment: Slightly different answer. In different incarnations she doesn't "hold" onto a power, but rather Rogue seems to copy all the traits of an individual she touches and this process knocks the victim out. Rogue then has access to those traits immidiately. They appear to go away, but she still has access to them and can use them when she masters her power which seams to mean she's making a copy and has surface access for the length of time it takes to assimilate. The "scan" is what knocks the victim out, not the transfer of Essence as I called it...

Comment: So it's likely in the second case they'd just knock each other out and gain all the traits the other had copied, which if they are the same they'd gain nothing new.